# How to display a day from the Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, date-formatting

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
Date

19-12-2009
20-12-2010
.....
```

Date Column datatype is `DATETIME`.

Expected Output

```
Monday
Tuesday
```

How to make a query for getting the day...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `DATENAME` function.

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[Date])
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 10):

As @Lamak suggested, you can use the [DATENAME function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) if you're on SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DateField) FROM Table
```

On earlier versions, the closest you could get was the [DATEPART function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) with `dw` as the interval, but you needed a CASE to convert the number returned to the day name, [as seen here](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/get-week-day-name-of-date-using-t-sql.aspx).

```
SELECT CASE DATEPART(dw, DateField)
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
       WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
       WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
       WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
       END AS DayOfWeek
FROM Table
```

Also note the remarks on the MSDN documentation for those date functions, for information about specifying which day of the week is considered the *first* day (depends on the `DATEFORMAT` setting of your SQL environment).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference for [DateName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) which will assist you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

If you want a numerical Reference like Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7, then use [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

This is what you want

```
DateName(dw, [Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest to set the language before get the week day

```
SET LANGUAGE 'Italian'
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from table where weekday(column_name = 'monday');
```

It prints whoever born on monday it displays their names

Comment: If you are interested in answering questions here, please learn to use code formatting.